# Most recurring element in a large file

Tags: c++

Given a large file, that cannot be loaded into the memory, with 2 fields, ItemId and its description. Entry contains the list of all items sold. Track the most sold item item at any instant.
Can we use min heap/max heap for this or is there any other efficient method?

Comment: How about using `std::map<std::string, unsigned int>`?  The `std::string` would be the item name (or ID) and the `unsigned int` would be the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a `map<string,int>` that counts the occurrences of each item.

Then sort it by count.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question was associated to LRU cache implmentation, where mostly bought products should stay in cache and any time you can pull all products from cache.

What I have experienced, these ques are asked in Amazons interview.

Another variation for same is,

In browser history, get 100 mostly opened pages.

when user open any page, updateHistory/getHistory....

Check http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-lru-cache/